# How to copy column values from one database to empty column in other database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two databases.

1. Alarm
2. TMP

I have a table in Alarm, where in a table there is one empty column with null values.
And I have a single column table in TMP.

I want to copy this single column values to my table in Alarm database.

What I tried so far is,

```
update [Alarm].[dbo].[AlarmDetails] set Alarm_Message = (select * from [TMP].[dbo].[AlarmDetails$])
where 1=1
```

The error is

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value.
```

Please note this,

```
NOTE: There is no id column in source table. Only one table & one column, Alarm Message.
```

I know the cause of error, but how should I modify my SQL.

Thank You.

Comment: Please note here, sequence is not a matter to me. I just want to copy those all values.

Comment: There must be some relations between the values in tmp and the alarm table. Does it matter which value from tmp goes into which line in alarm?

Comment: No. It doesn't matter. I just want to copy from source to destination.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of copying a column:

```
update  dst
set     Alarm_Message = src.AlarmMessage
from    Alarm.dbo.AlarmDetails dst
join    TMP.dbo.AlarmDetails src
on      dst.id = src.id
```

You did not specify how the tables are related, so I assumed they both have an `id` column.

Comment: No. there is no id column in source table. Only one column, Alarm Message.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this.

```
update t1 
set
t1.<something1> = t2.<something2>
from
[Alarm].[dbo].[AlarmDetails] t1
join [TMP].[dbo].[AlarmDetails] t2 on (t1.<cols1> = t2.<cols2>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE results SET results.platform_to_insert = (
    SELECT correct_platform
    FROM build
    WHERE results.BuildID=build.BuildID LIMIT 1
);
```